# Cloud function unexpected token - in apns-collapse-id

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have written a firebase cloud function to send notifications on IOS and Android devices. I want collapsible notification messages. This is what is written [in documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=1):

> Collapsible : When there is a newer message that renders an older, related message irrelevant to the client app, FCM replaces the older message. For example: messages used to initiate a data sync from the server, or outdated notification messages.
>
> Set the appropriate parameter in your message request:
>
> collapseKey on Android
>
> apns-collapse-id on iOS

so I have the following lines of code in my function:

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: `Hey`,
          body: 'Your turn',
          sound: 'default',
        }
      };

const options = {
    collapseKey: 'myturnkey',
    apns-collapse-id: 'myturnkey',
  };
```

But I get the following message when I try to deploy the rule in terminal:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

I also tried with apns-collapse-id and I get a slightly different message for the same line of code:

> Invalid or unexpected token

Do you see what is wrong ?

EDIT

with:

```
const options = {
    'apns-collapse-id': 'myturnkey',
  };
```

I can deploy the rule but the notifications do not collapse

And with:

```
const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: `hey`,
              body: 'your turn',
              sound: 'default',
            }
          };

const patchedPayload = Object.assign({}, payload, {
        apns: {
            headers: {
                'apns-collapse-id': 'myturnkey',
            }
        }
    });
```

I get the following error message in my firebase cloud functions logs when the function is called:

> Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid "apns" property. Valid
>   properties are "data" and "notification".

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Do you have the same issue still.