# How to use collapse-id in Firebase Messaging

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to update my older `FCM` PN message with a new one when received on `iOS` devices in XF application.

The documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) says to use `apns-collapse-id`, I have tried sending the messages with `apns-collapse-id`through but the older messages never gets updated rather the newer one adds to the statcks withe the older one.

Has anyone tried this ?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054592/why-cant-i-collapse-my-push-notifications-when-i-use-firebase-fcm

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFTHi , tried sending the apns-collapse-id in the header through postman . Didn't worked :(